# Dropping a typeclass instance and the package version policy

Tags: haskell

I've [been asked to drop my dependency on `system-filepath`](https://github.com/rampion/ReadArgs/issues/7).

My package defines a typeclass `Arguable`, and defines an instance for `Filesystem.Path`'s `FilePath` type. No `system-filepath` means no `Filesystem.Path` means no `FilePath`, so by dropping this dependency, I'd be changing my API to no longer provide the `Arguable` instance.

How does that line up with the PVP? Is this a major version change?

Comment: Yes, this is a major version change. Adding or removing type-classes constitutes a possibly breaking change and [should be packaged as a major version change](https://wiki.haskell.org/Package_versioning_policy#Leaking_instances).

Comment: @recursion.ninja Actually, *adding* non-orphan instances is specifically exempt (this is a relatively recent adjustment). But not removing them.

Comment: These comments look answer worthy to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a major version change. The [Haskell wiki page on the PVP](https://wiki.haskell.org/Package_versioning_policy#Version_numbers) states about A.B.C version numbers (relevant phrase bolded):

> 1. If any entity was removed, or the types of any entities or the definitions of datatypes or classes were changed, or orphan instances were added **or any instances were removed**, then the new A.B must be greater than the previous A.B. Note that modifying imports or depending on a newer version of another package may cause extra orphan instances to be exported and thus force a major version change.
> 2. Otherwise, if only new bindings, types, classes, non-orphan instances or modules (but see below) were added to the interface, then A.B may remain the same but the new C must be greater than the old C. Note that modifying imports or depending on a newer version of another package may cause extra non-orphan instances to be exported and thus force a minor version change.
> 3. Otherwise, A.B.C may remain the same (other version components may change).